Does GitLab Pages provide ability to serve static assets?
I'm working on a ui-component library and we use Storybook to preview our components. To access our assets (icons, images, fonts) we use absolute domain paths like so /public/icons.
This approach works fine in both a local Storybook and an actual project, but doesn't work in a Storybook which is published to GitLab Pages.
In remote Storybook I get following error:

Browser says that it can't load resource by given path, but the file is there, under the right path in the project folder.
Also, if I run the storybook build with http-server, everything works fine.
I wonder if GitLab Pages able to serve/access static assets or they must be inlined inside of JavaScript bundles?
